# How to put my subtotals in the last record of every group

Tags: crystal-reports

I created new report using crystal report. I inserted 2 groups namely: Classification(1st Group),Category(2nd Group) and i have my QTY Column it is the summation of My Group Category. Now i want to display my sub totals of my group a line with the last record in the QTY Column.

Please see the attached image.

[image]

Regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already find the solution on my problem. Just create a formula as your running total and create another formula for the summation of every group in your report then suppress the formula field using a formula.

Formulas:

1. @RunningTotal
2. @SummationOfEveryGroup

Example: right click the `@RunningTotal` Field then in the suppress use the below formula:

`IF {@RunningTotal} = {@SummationofEveryGroup} THEN false ELSE true`

Regards.